# Create single variable from while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to place a while loop into a variable that I can use as a single echo. What is happening is that the loop is only displaying the first record.

All db connections are in place and connected. I would appreciate it if someone could point out my error. Many thanks

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result1) >0) {
    $msgread = "";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) { 
        $msgread = "<FONT COLOR='1d99f0'>" . "<b>" . $row['to_user'] . "</b>" . "</font>";
        $msgread .= "<p />";
        $msgread .= date("d/m/Y");
        $msgread .= "<p />";
        $msgread .= $row['message'];
        $msgread .= "<p />";
        $msgread .= $row['from_user'];
    }

    $error1 = false;
}

if($error1 == 0)  {     
    echo $msgread;               
}
```

Comment: You have a closing bracket at the end of the msgread attribution. Identation matters here, don't avoid it. Could it be that?

Comment: Does your DB query return more than 1 record?

Comment: You can store them in array and than run the foreach loop? if its ok

Comment: db query returns all records. Do you have example arif. Thanks

Comment: can you show the format you want ?

Comment: @user1532468 i think you got the answer which you want. if not let me know. sorry i did not read your comment. as i did not recieve the notification. As you did not use @ when you posted the comment

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting it each loop, it should be `.=`:

```
$msgread = "";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {

   $msgread = "<FONT COLOR='1d99f0'>" . "<b>" . $row['to_user'] . "</b>" . "</font>";
            ^^ it gets overwritten each loop
```

Should be like:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result1) >0) {

    $msgread = ""; // initialize

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {

        $msgread .= "<FONT COLOR='1d99f0'><b>" . $row['to_user'] . "</b></font>";
              // ^ concatenation
        $msgread .= "<p>" . date("d/m/Y") . '</p>';
        $msgread .= "<p>" . $row['message'] . '</p>';
        $msgread .= "<p>" . $row['from_user'] . '</p>';           
    }

    echo $msgread; // then echo

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.` in the while loop's first line 
`$msgread .= "<FONT COLOR='1d99f0'>" . "<b>" . $row['to_user'] . "</b>" . "</font>";`

Answer (score 0):

You have missed  `.` on the line `$msgread = "<FONT COLOR='1d99f0'>" . "<b>" . $row['to_user'] . "</b>" . "</font>";`

It would be `$msgread .= "<FONT COLOR='1d99f0'>" . "<b>" . $row['to_user'] . "</b>" . "</font>";`